# What tag should one use to get a question answered with elisp code?

Tags: discussion

Using the `elisp` tag is not appropriate, but what tag *should* one use when when wants a solution in the form of elisp code, not a setting a `custom` variable, or a `key-sequence`, or some other mechanism supported by emacs?  Shouldn't there be a tag for that?  Conversely, should there be tags for the other cases too?  E.g. when one wants a key-sequence to use (something like what `apropos` gives, but possibly specialized for cases one is using a mechanism `isearch` or works only in a `kmacro`).  Or something one could use `customize` to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a tag for that. In most cases, the differences between what you describe as different kinds of answers are really not that big. It's very common to see an answer of the form:

> You can do X with `M-x special-feature`, bound to `M-x C-s` by default. You can also set this in your init file with `(setq special-feature-mode t)`. See also the customization group "Special Feature".

Additionally, I don't think we really want to have separate questions for "How do I do X with elisp?", and "How do I do X with Customize?". The answers would be near identical, but would make the search results twice as long.

Comment: Ok, I guess I can understand that perspective.